# Check For Process.Start Termination

Tags: c#, wpf

So for my recent project I need to put the content generated by A console app in a WPF textBox.
The point is the app generates the text file `(test.txt)` only after process completion which can take some time.

Here's the code for the same:

```
foreach (var website in lst) //list can have several entries.
            {
                var args = "-v -all -text test.txt n" + website.ToString() + " 443";
                Process.Start(@"C:\TestSSLServer.exe", args);

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    MyValue = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

                });
            }
```

How do I make sure that the text box is only populated when the console app `TestSSLServer` quits?

**Edit:** `Process.WaitForExit();` does not work. I tried it :( Still throws file not found exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) to block until the process exits.

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\TestSSLServer.exe", args);
p.WaitForExit();
```

I would note that this will block whatever thread it's run on.  If you want to be *notified* when the process exits instead use the [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Doesn't work. I still get the file not found exception.

Comment: Well, does the file exist?  You didn't mention anything about a `FileNotFoundException`  Also, it looks like you're overwriting the same file in the loop - should you read from the text file synchronously instead of spawning a thread?

Comment: Overwriting is the point. I want to read the file and append it to the text box. I am really not much experienced with threads so I may have screwed there.

Comment: Yeah I was going to ask why you were spawning a thread.  I would just make it synchronous since you can't really benefit from parallelism since you're reusing the same file.  You could spawn the _entire process_ on a separate thread if you don;t want to block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the process in a variable of type Process. Then you can set its EnableRaisingEvents flag to true and subscribe to the event signaling that the process has ended. Your handler should be the function which populates the text box.

Sample code is available on MSDN.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Judging by your edit, you have a bit of an XY problem going on... you didn't make it clear that you were getting a `FileNotFoundException`. So is the process you're spawning actually creating the file? Your list of arguments, specifically the argument that's just a plain `n`, looks suspicious.